# Widevine to encrypt all type of content and how to implement

Tags: widevine

Can Google Widevine be used to protect content of any type or it is just for videos? I can't find any implementation guide lines to utilize it

Answer (score 0):

From what I saw so far, it is supposed to be for audio and video. Widevine web does not talk about [anything else](http://www.widevine.com/wv_drm.html).

In theory, Widevine should work for any type of content because it is just a key management and some cryptographic operations on buffer of encrypted data. In practice you are limited by the API exposed by the platform - they will not give you low level access to decryption functionality to pass in custom data. For example EME in browser or MediaDrm on Android, are expected to be used with audio and video content.